Problemas con los simbolos \ ¥
Quiero colocar el símbolo \ en NetBeans pero se cambia por el símbolo del yen ¥, así lo copie y pegue el símbolo sigue cambiando.


tus archivos no estan en utf8, y posiblemente tampoco tu IDE

Para que utilizar ese símbolo al mostrar los datos??

Algunos consejos


Utiliza el separador de líneas ("\n"). esto te evita el problema de caracteres extraños en el programa.
En vez de utilizar un método para mostrar los datos, puedes sobrescribir la función toString() de java utilizando @override.

@override
public String toString(){
    String message = "Marca : " + marca + "\n" + "Modelo: " + modelo + "\n" 
                         + "Precio: " + precio + "\n";
    return message;
}

Exitos!

Tu solución es usa "" pero su problema es que le cambia las "" por el símbolo de yen... literalmente no le respondes para nada a su pregunta.
